# Null Safe Operator for Cakephp Find Condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to find an item that has a field that is not equal to another field on CakePHP.

What I'm trying to do (doesn't work, it still shows the item that is equal to another) :

```
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array(
            array('fieldA' => null),
            array('fieldA' => 'fieldB')
        )
    )
);
```

Basically, I need to figure out how to use the [MySQL <=> (NULL-safe equal to operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825237/mysql-select-rows-where-two-columns-do-not-have-the-same-value) on CakePHP's ORM.

It's not as obvious as the following:

```
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array(
            array('fieldA <=>' => 'fieldB')
        )
    )
);
```

The above does not work for me :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array(
            array('fieldA <=> fieldB')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you!, You've just proved that I'm a total idiot. I've tried `array('fieldA <=>' => 'fieldB')` and `array('fieldA <' => '> fieldB')`. But not the one that you've posted, I need break. Thank you AGAIN.