# How to compare two columns not having same value using sequelize orm

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two fields in my table `dispatchCount & qty`.

I want to `findOne` tuple where `dispatchCount` is not equal to `qty`

I want to do something similar to this ([Mysql Select Rows Where two columns do not have the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825237/mysql-select-rows-where-two-columns-do-not-have-the-same-value)) but using sequelize ORM.

I don't want to write the raw query myself bcz there are a lot of aliases & things like that. So how can I do the following using sequelize

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE column_a != column_b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the solution without writing raw query to do so :-

```js
let en = Entity.findOne({
    where: {
        dispatchCount : {
            [Op.ne]: sequelize.col("qty");
        }
    }
})
```